# Logging into Game Kit Sandbox Problems

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, sandbox, gamekit, game-center

I am trying to use Game Kit for leader boards and achievements. I am trying to login using the code in the Apple documents. It works fine apart from it isn't logging into the sandbox. It pops up the pannel asking if I want to "Use Existing Account", "Create New Account" or "Cancel". Now I've seen in tutorials before, under the "Sign in to Game Center" title it says " * * * Sandbox * * * ", however mine does not.

I have set it up in iTunes Connect, I have created a Provisioning Profile and everything has the same bundle identifier (including in the xcode Project). I have even added **gameKit BOOL YES** into the info.plist. It's driving me slightly spare so any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. I am also using Cocos2D though I can't see how this would be affecting me logging in sandbox mode.

If anybody has anything they can sugest or has experienced this problem, please let me know.

Thanks again everybody.

Baza

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this problem a long time ago but I thought I'd tie up the loose end.

It was basically from my own ignorance. When testing a Game Center App you need to create a Apple ID via iTunes Connect -> Manage Users and then create a test user.

Simple solution and came from me skimming the docs and not reading them properly. Lesson learnt. :-D

Answer (score 0):

Its because your jailbroken. It likely has to do with AppSync, there was a problem a few months ago where everyone was getting put into the sandbox for any game center app. After several attempts at fixing it with no success, they probably went ape s*** and disabled all kinds of sandbox stuff. After several hours of digging, I have not found a way to get into the sandbox. Partially because the Google results are littered with links trying to DISABLE the sandbox.

Comment: Nope. I haven't jailbroken my phone. Slightly odd you'd asume that as a developer I don't know why you'd jailbreak your phone since you wouldn't know if something was playing up from the jailbreak or a real bug. Ether way, thats for your suggestion ether way. :)

Comment: Hmm, I've never seen anyone have this problem that wasn't jailbroken. Un-jailbreaking was the only way I have seen to fix this problem.